# how to deploy war on embedded tomcat

Tags: java, jenkins, war, web-deployment, embedded-tomcat-8

In our project we have Apache tomcat running on 8080 and we have deployed jenkins war file there. As we are on client infra, we cannot have more ports open. We have to deploy the sonarcube also , but sonar cube 5.5 does not support war deployment as support for this already ended in sonarcube 4. 
Now I am trying the other way around of deployment ie deploying jenkins war on sonar cube embedded tomcat instance. 
 As compare to normal tomcat directory structure sonar cube doesn't have webapps directory,so I am blocked.
Can anybody suggest a better way or how I can deploy a war on 8080 and sonar cube on embedded tomcat on 8080.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Install a reverse proxy listening on port 8080, change the port of your jenkins tomcat, and configure the reverse proxy to route requests to jenkins to the jenkins server, and requests to sonar to the sonar server (using virtual hosts, for example).